# How can I calculate the singularities and residues of...?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$$\frac{e^z}{z^3(z-1)}+\frac{1}{z^3}$$

I have problems specially for $z=0$

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{z^3} = \frac{z-1}{z^3(z-1)},$$ so how does $e^z + (z-1)$ behave at $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer It's a pole of order 3.

Comment: No, the order is $2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why 2?

Comment: Because $e^z + (z-1)$ has a simple zero at $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, but I don't get it.

Comment: If you have $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^k}$ where $f$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $0$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $g$ has a removable singularity or a pole at $0$. If $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $0$, you can write $f(z) = z^m\cdot h(z)$, with $h$ holomorphic and $h(0) \neq 0$. That gives you $g(z) = z^{m-k}\cdot h(z)$. When has $g$ a removable singularity at $0$, and when a pole? If a pole, what is the order?

Comment: Dear @dralion94 First of all welcome to the MSE site. I see that, although you have already asked 3 question in this site and received answers in all three of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{e^z}{z^3(z-1)}+\frac{1}{z^3}=\frac{e^z+z-1}{z^3(z-1)}=\frac{2z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{6}+\ldots}{z^3(z-1)}=\frac{2+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots}{z^2(z-1)}$$
and since:
$$\left(2+\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{6}+\ldots\right)\left(1+z+z^2+\ldots\right)=2+\frac{5 z}{2}+\frac{8 z^2}{3}+\ldots$$
we have:
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{z^3(z-1)}+\frac{1}{z^3},z=0\right)=\color{red}{-\frac{5}{2}}.$$

Comment: But then the residue would be 0, the $z^{-1}$ coefficient is zero.

Comment: @dralion94: you did not divide the second line by $-z^2$.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the residue by using the limit formula?

Comment: @dralion94: sure, just the limit formula for a double pole: $$\text{Res}(f(z),z=0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}(z^2 f(z)).$$

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I'm not able to reach the final result. I put the limit in Wolfram Alpha and it gives me $\infty$

Comment: I think I helped enough. If you put Residue[Exp[z]/(z^3 (z - 1)) + 1/z^3, {z, 0}] in WA it gives $-5/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!. What I was doing was enter the expression for the limit in WA.